# Creating only single record after loop iterates using flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, configuration, lightning-flow-builder, salesforce-flow

Is there are any way where we can create only one record after a loop iteration completes in salesforce via a flow?.

Scenario:
On Account object there is a field called Active if that field becomes active on after update context I have to create a record in xyz object.
This will work perfectly with a single Account record in a flow.
But if there are 10 accounts becoming active at the same time and you iterate them over a loop and using at the last element in the loop I try to create only one record in xyz object. It looks like it is taking record by record of account object and is creating 10 records in xyz object.

#Flow #FlowBuilder #CRM Configuration

Comment: Hello @Ajay, the `Flow` will execute the logic correctly, it's just working on whenever account is set as "Active". In Your scenario, during Bulk update.. can you please provide how you're like to group (based on which field value) that record action based on only one xyz object record need to be created?

Comment: @MohanRaj There is a field  called active, if 10 accounts are being updated and if all 10 are active = true, then only record in xyz object to be created.